# Evaluating statistic significance in Neighbour Nearest Test using QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatial-statistics, nearest-neighbor, spatial-cluster, health

I'm reviewing a scientific article to be publish.
I tried to evidence that pathogens collected from different geographic areas clustered. I used Nearest Neighbour test to prove it. However, I've noticed that no p-value is assigned in my output.

How could I get the p-value from my analysis?

This is the output obtained from my analysis using QGIS3:

Observed mean distance: 495.1212145321877

Expected mean distance: 654.1975182291224

Nearest neighbour index: 0.7568375005036007

Number of points: 28

Z-Score: -2.46153773279898

Comment: It's unfortunate. Any chance you'll try Whitebox-GAT's Nearest-Neighbour Analysis tool?

Comment: Unfortunately the native tool in QGIS does not output a p-value. Your Z-Score would indicate clustering in your dataset. You can infer a confidence level by looking at a critical value and your sample size but I would like to point out that a sample size of 28 is below what is recommended.

Comment: My sample size is 45. I think a solution might be the following: since Z-score is based on the standard normal variate, I can calculate the p under the curve. For α=0.05, Z would take values +/-1.96, so if |Z| > Zα/2 indicates a significant clustering pattern, otherwise my sample is overdispersed.